# When parsing JSON data from web service, no data returned

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing

I'm trying to populate a UITableView from the results from a call to a web service. The data is returned in JSON format as below

```
[{"name":"CONTROL TEST",
"nc_lead":"TOM SMITH",
"datastr":"N/A",
"username":"tsmith",
"status":"REOPENED",
"orderno":"00000000",
"ccsText":"000",
"risk":0,
"dateTimeCreated":"2016-01-29 13:16:50",
"supplyStart":"2016-02-08T11:51:00+0000",
"supplyEnd":"2016-02-08T12:03:00+0000",
"logs":
    [{"dateTime":"2016-02-02 11:26:18",
    "statusChangeDateTime":"2016-02-02 00:00:00",
    "user":"tsmith",
    "uid":1,
    "task":"TESTING",
    "info":"state changed to 'Y'",
    "x":456123,
    "y":362514,
    "id_log":28294},
   {“dateTime":"2016-02-02 10:54:34", 
        "statusChangeDateTime":"2016-02-02 10:54:00",
    "user":"tsmith",
    "uid":1,
    "task":"TESTING",
    "info":"T Smith changed area.",
    "x":452356,
    "y":325489,
    "id_log":28291
   },.....
```

There is no key as the first part is formed by 12 values as a header and then the logs form an array of values for each header. I return my JSON object using the code below, parsing the data object from my web service call.

```
let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)
```

I can see the return value for data using the code below

```
let str = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
```

then I've tried using code such as the code below to extract a value for 'name' but it doesn't work

```
if let name = json["name"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {}
```

How can I iterate through my json object to get the data from the header and the logs array?

Comment: your json is array of dictionary and "name" is string

Comment: try json[0]["name"]

Comment: What you get by this line : `let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments)` ? have you print `josn` ?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I originally had json declared as NSDictionary which returned nil, when I changed it to NSArray it returned 15 values but I could not access them. Also using json[0]["name"] doesn't work and under debug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `json` object is an array of dictionary, so you should do something like this:

```
if let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:.AllowFragments) as? Array<Dictionary<String, AnyObject>> {
    for item in json {
        if let dict = item as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
            print(dict["name"])
        }
    }
}
```

The conversion should be to `AnyObject` because sometimes the value is `String`, like for example `dict["name"] == "CONTROL TEST"`, but `dict["logs"]` is `Array<Dictionary<String, String>>`. Do you see it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, what is Anydata?